# How to automatically save the time stamp of when a record is added / updated in the Firebase cloud database

Tags: debugging, firebase, cloud, synchronized, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to **log when a node is created in the server**?

In other words, when a data is "eventually saved" is it possible to log the **effective write time**?

Approach already considered:

- I understand that I can add a value "date" on the node and set it to the time in which the command has been issued. However this does not guarantee that the time will be the same as when is actually written on the server.

What I am trying to **measure**:

- **delay** between save requests and actual node data "writing" on the cloud
- this would allow me to **measure the impact of lack of internet connection on my application data synchronisation service**

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything like that in the docs, so I would say it is pretty safe to say it is impossible.

Like you said, you can use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. If you knew for sure that the client time you have is synced with that of the Firebase servers, then you could combine like this

```
wantedSaveTime: [client time],
actualSaveTime: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

But, syncing clocks is difficult. If estimates and averages are good enough (like measuring offline time), then the above suggestion might be ok.